Adding elements to the array based on condition
I have 2 ids ultimateId and Id. If both id's are there in input then I need to add ultimateId related object to the output list. If i have only id but not ultimateId then I have to add id related object to the output list.
INPUT:
{
  "accountType": "CUSTOMER",
  "AccountInfo": {
    "ultimateId": "DF6ECC32",
    "id": "DJKWNA"
  },
  "AccountAddresses": [
    {
      "modId": "Al-Jazeera",
      "businessAddressEndDateTime": "2020-07-01T00:00:00.00Z"
    }
  ],
  "PartyDetails": {
    "domesticUltimateDunsPostalCode": "94115",
    "subIndustryCode": "1232"
  }
}

SPECS:
[
  {
    "operation": "shift",
    "spec": {
      "AccountInfo": {
        "id": {
          "@2,partyAltIdResellerUidSrcKey": "PartyAlternateId.item[#2].key.sourceKey",
          "@1,resellerUId": "PartyAlternateId.item[#2].AltIdVal",
          "@2,created": "PartyAlternateId.item[#2].EffStrtDt",
          "#ID": "PartyAlternateId.item[#2].AltIdType.idTypDesc",
          "#0004": "PartyAlternateId.item[#2].AltIdType.idTyp"
        },
        "ultimateId": {
          "@2,partyAltIdUltimateResellerUidSrcKey": "PartyAlternateId.item[#2].key.sourceKey",
          "@1,resellerUltimateSalesLegacySourceId": "PartyAlternateId.item[#2].AltIdVal",
          "@2,created": "PartyAlternateId.item[#2].EffStrtDt",
          "#Ultimate ID": "PartyAlternateId.item[#2].AltIdType.idTypDesc",
          "#0018": "PartyAlternateId.item[#2].AltIdType.idTyp"
        }
      }
    }
  }
]

output I am getting for above specs:
{
  "PartyAlternateId": {
    "item": [
      {
        "AltIdType": {
          "idTypDesc": "ID",
          "idTyp": "0004"
        }
      },
      {
        "AltIdType": {
          "idTypDesc": "Ultimate ID",
          "idTyp": "0018"
        }
      }
    ]
  }
}

Desired Output if input have both id and ultimateId:
{
  "PartyAlternateId": {
    "item": [
      {
        "AltIdType": {
          "idTypDesc": "Ultimate ID",
          "idTyp": "0018"
        }
      }
    ]
  }
}

Desired Output if input have only id but not ultimateId:
{
  "PartyAlternateId": {
    "item": [
      {
        "AltIdType": {
          "idTypDesc": "ID",
          "idTyp": "0004"
        }
      }
    ]
  }
}


You can add a modify transformation spec along with a lastElement function such as
[
  {
    "operation": "shift",
    "spec": {
      "AccountInfo": {
        "id": {
          "@2,partyAltIdResellerUidSrcKey": "PartyAlternateId.item[#2].key.sourceKey",
          "@1,resellerUId": "PartyAlternateId.item[#2].AltIdVal",
          "@2,created": "PartyAlternateId.item[#2].EffStrtDt",
          "#ID": "PartyAlternateId.item[#2].AltIdType.idTypDesc",
          "#0004": "PartyAlternateId.item[#2].AltIdType.idTyp"
        },
        "ultimateId": {
          "@2,partyAltIdUltimateResellerUidSrcKey": "PartyAlternateId.item[#2].key.sourceKey",
          "@1,resellerUltimateSalesLegacySourceId": "PartyAlternateId.item[#2].AltIdVal",
          "@2,created": "PartyAlternateId.item[#2].EffStrtDt",
          "#Ultimate ID": "PartyAlternateId.item[#2].AltIdType.idTypDesc",
          "#0018": "PartyAlternateId.item[#2].AltIdType.idTyp"
        }
      }
    }
  },
  {//pick the last component of the "item" array  
    "operation": "modify-overwrite-beta",
    "spec": {
      "*": {
        "*": "=lastElement(@(1,&))"
      }
    }
  },
  {//nest item object with array wrapper and convert it back to an array
    "operation": "modify-overwrite-beta",
    "spec": {
      "*": {
        "item": "=toList"
      }
    }
  }
]


will it work if there are multiple items in the item array? if multiple items are there How can I check if ultimateId is there or not in array, if it is then only remove id element from item array

I'll be expanding the answer when I'm available @Madhavikurabalakota , btw welcome to SO
